# SQL query to delete/identify cross linked data in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've a SQL DB table ABC, in that I've two columns i.e. column1 and column2.

In this table I have some data like.

```
column1     column2
-------------------
1           2
1           7
2           1
3           4
7           1
4           3
```

Now, I have to delete the data  from this table which are cross linked to each other. for e.g.

```
(1,2) are cross linked to (2,1)
(1,7) are cross linked to (7,1)
(3,4) are cross linked to (4,3)
```

So, I need to delete one of value from this pair. My final output should be like:

```
column1     column2
-------------------
1           2
1           7
3           4
```

OR

```
column1     column2
-------------------
2           1
4           3
7           1
```

I want to write a sql query to do this. Anyone has any idea how can I achieved this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
<kbd>[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bb42/15)</kbd>

```
with  pairs as (select 
    case when c1< c2 then c1 else c2 end as minc,
    case when c1< c2 then c2 else c1 end as maxc
  from t
  group by
    case when c1< c2 then c1 else c2 end ,
    case when c1< c2 then c2 else c1 end 
  having count(*) >1) 
select * 
from t
where not exists
(select * from pairs
 where c1= minc and c2= maxc
)
```

### Explain

- The CTE table returns all paired rows of one side.
- Through `NOT EXISTS`, it returns all rows not paired

  - If you change the condition of `where c1= minc and c2= maxc` to `where c2= minc and c1= maxc` will get the opposite side of the pairs.
  - If you want delete one side of those pairs, with `DELETE FROM T WHERE EXISTS` instead of `NOT EXISTS`

There have some different ways to get paired rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* FROM test A LEFT JOIN test B
ON A.column1 = B.column2 AND A.column2 = B.column
WHERE B.column IS NULL;
```

This should work, assuming your OK with something like (2,2) also being excluded.